# Update each individual record instead of the whole table

Tags: sql, teradata

I loaded a table which contains default timestamp columns like so '1900-01-01 00:00:00'. The table structure is simple

```
PARTID|GMT_TMSTMP|PAC_TMSTMP
```

But I need to change these timestamp values to US Pacific time based on the value of another column which is in GMT time.

I figured out a way to do it for one record

```
UPDATE STG SET PAC_TMSTMP=CAST(GMT_TMSTMP AS TIMESTAMP(0)) AT TIME ZONE 'America Pacific' WHERE PARTID='0369526767';
```

The table contains over a million records and I think that doing a self join, I can update each record like so

```
UPDATE    STG      SET
PAC_TMSTMP =CAST(GMT_TMSTMP AS TIMESTAMP(0)) AT TIME ZONE 'America Pacific'
FROM    STG  A    JOIN    STG  B    ON      A.PARTID = B.PARTID
```

Teradata is giving me an error and excepts something before the FROM keyword. I am obviously getting mixed up.

Can this be done?

Comment: Do you want to just update every record in your table?

Comment: If i understand correctly, doesn't your `first update statement without the where clause`, get the job done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do a single table update for to set one column's value based on another column in the same table:

```
 UPDATE STG
    SET PAC_TMPSTMP = CAST(GMT_TMSTMP AS TIMESTAMP(0)) --AS TIME ZONE 'America Pacific";
```

This will require transient journaling and if this is something you are doing more than once you may wish to consider looking into the `MERGE` statement as an alternative.

Comment: Well, that is embarrassing. The simplest solution is usually the best: `UPDATE STG  SET
PAC_TMSTMP =CAST(GMT_TMSTMP AS TIMESTAMP(0)) AT TIME ZONE 'America Pacific'` did the trick. Thanks, Rob. Accepted and voted up.